# What is the snippet shortname?

Tags: name

For template the shortname is usually `tpl` and filenames can be written as `tpl-projects`.

What is the best shortname for snippet?

```
sni
snp
spt
```

Anything else? I need a 3 characters long shortname.

Comment: `/snippets/` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web there are many cases where `spt` is used so I guess that would be the most correct shortname for it.

**An example:**

https://github.com/vim-scripts/snippet.vim/blob/master/doc/snippet.txt

Search for `spt` in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Why are we stuck in a way of thinking that file extensions must be 3 characters?  This is a throwback to the days of DOS - *who can remember that :o)* - that had a 3 character limitation.

Wouldn't it be much easier for users if your file was named `dosomething.snippet` rather than `dosomething.spt`?

There is no limitation apart from a total length of 255 characters, be creative.

Have a look here as well https://superuser.com/questions/315393/there-is-a-length-limit-to-windows-file-extensions

Comment: I will not use it as a file extension, just as a 3 char prefix.

Comment: DOH!  Had I read the original question properly.  But my comment stands :o)